# Why does my Luhn algorithm code not return anything?

Tags: c

I finished putting these functions together yesterday and it's basically meant to be an implementation of the Luhn algorithm. The first function is supposed to take an integer and array as input then split the integer into digits to fill the array. And the second is supposed to check if the number is valid and return 1 or 0. My issue is that as far as I can tell my code looks okay and doesn't give any errors or warnings but when I try to run it nothing happens. I'd appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance

```
int populate_array(int raw_num, int num_array[]){
    //Assume length of raw_num will always be 9

    num_array= malloc(sizeof(int)*9); //Allocate memory for num_array
    int count=9;

    while (raw_num){
        num_array[count]=raw_num%10;
        raw_num=raw_num/10;
        count--;
        }
    return 0;
}

/*
*Takes an 9 element integer array representing a candidateSIN number.
*It returns 0 if the number given is a valid Canadian SIN number, and 1 otherwise.
*/

int sin_checker(int sin_array[]){ 
    int sin_sum=0;

    for (int i=1; i<9; i+=2){
        sin_array[i]*=2; 
        }

    for (int j=0; j<9;j++){
        if (sin_array[j]>9){
            sin_sum+= sin_array[j]/10;
            sin_sum+= sin_array[j]%10;
        }
        else{
            sin_sum+=sin_array[j];
        }
    }

    if (sin_sum % 10==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the first iteration `num_array[9]` breaks the bounds of the allocated memory. Also, the memory pointer allocated to `num_array` is discarded when the function returns, resulting in a memory leak. Moreover, why does this `populate_array` function return a value, when it is always `0`?

Comment: ... and even if it did work, how would the caller know how many digits are in that array? If `raw_num` is `5` there will be one element. If `raw_num` is `42` there will be two elements. Perhaps that is what the function should return.

Comment: populate_array returns 0 because its meant to be the else case, I removed the if case for testing purposes but it would have returned 1 if its condition was met. As for the memory being exceeded, how exactly does that happen?

Comment: Your populate code returns 0 under all circumstances.  Given that, it may as well be a `void` function.  It would be better, though, if it returned the length of the array.

Comment: An array of 9 elements may be indexed from 0 thru 8 - this is **elementary**.

Comment: If someone is cruel enough to pass a 10-digit number to the code, you overwrite the boundaries.  You don't enforce that the number is plausibly valid (bigger than zero, less than 1 billion) — at least, not in the code shown, but that's all we have to go on.  (Please read about creating an MCVE — [MCVE] — because an MCVE helps us see what's crucial and what's incidental much better.)

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit to the question, for testing purposes assume the length of the raw_num is always 9

Comment: A 32-bit `int` may well be a 10-digit number.

Comment: 32-bit in is +/- 2,147,483,647, unsigned is 4,294,967,295.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate a new array num_array of size int[9]. Either use the one passed, or allocate a new one if passed NULL.

```
#define MAXDIGITS (10)

int*
populate_array(int raw_num, int* num_array)
{
    if(!num_array)
        num_array= malloc(sizeof(int)*9); //Allocate memory for num_array
    int count=MAXDIGITS-1;
    while (raw_num != 0){
        num_array[count--]=raw_num%10;
        if(count<0) break;
        raw_num=raw_num/10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Call this either by passing NULL, and using returned pointer, or pass array,

```
int stuff[9];
int* pstuff = NULL;
populate_array(12345, stuff);
pstuff = populate_array(98765, NULL);
//then either print stuff, or pstuff
```